# Is there any programming language in which you can override a method of 2 classes up?

Tags: oop

For example, if you have class A, class B inheriting A, and class C inheriting B, is there any programming language in which class C can override a method of class A, even if class B don't override it?

```
class A {
  method() {}
}

class B extends A{
}

class C extends B {
  //override method from A
  method(){}
}
```

Comment: Yes.  I thought every OO language lets you do that...

Comment: Actually, I know no one, just misunderstood my book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you can do this in most (if not all) OO languages, e.g. in Java and C++ for sure.

Answer (score 1):

yes , It is very general case, Java does it.

Answer (score 0):

This ruby code does exactly what you want:

```
class A
  def hello
    puts "hello from class A"
  end
end

class B < A
end

class C < B
  def hello
    puts "hello from C"
  end
end

B.new.hello
C.new.hello
```

Once executed you will have the following output:

```
hello from class A
hello from C
```

Answer (score 0):

C# for one

```
public class A
{
    virtual public int retval(int x)
    {
        return x; 
    }
}
public class B : A
{

}
public class C : B
{
    public override int retval(int x)
    {
        return 3; 
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a  = new C();
        Console.WriteLine(a.retval(2).ToString());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think most common languages will allow that without difficulty if all modules are recompiled.  There is a gotcha in some (including C# and vb.net) if an override is added to a mid-level class which didn't have one when a child method was compiled.  In that scenario, if the child classes are not recompiled, calls to their parent methods may bypass the mid-level classes (since those mid-level classes didn't have overrides when the child passes were compiled).